# Embed Instagram (oembed) into Angular 2 app

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to embed an instagram post into a Component in Angular2. The developer [documentation of instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/) shows an option for oembed. But I can't seem to get the response back into the Component from the jsonp call.

```
import {Component, Init} from '@angular/core'
import {Jsonp} from '@angular/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `...`,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._jsonp.request('https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/&omitscript=true').subscribe();
  }
}
```

I get an error from the api: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*

But also: *EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL*

And if I check the response, I do get the json data. I've added a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0EE4B2o1SjYKK3h3DgvJ?p=preview) showing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add `&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK` at the end of your url, like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this._jsonp.request('https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN/&omitscript=true&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK').subscribe(); 
}
```

Comment: This was totally what I was looking for. Thank you, Jimmi!

Comment: This is doesn't work for me I get this erro Uncaught ReferenceError: __ng_jsonp____req0_finished is not defined